# High latency in elasticsearch as request volume decreases

Tags: java, elasticsearch, garbage-collection, ceph, heap-dump

I have a java application and elasticsearch with indices of size in order of 10 gig size.
There is strange scenario, which is during the night as request volume decreases response duration increases. I had checked server resources metric but nothing unusual found.

hear we have request volume diagram:

[image: Request Volume]

and request duration:

[image: Request duration]

as you see request duration maxima exactly lies at interval of request volume minima.
but when we check server resources nothing unusual can be seen:

[image: Server Resource]

I must mention that no special config has been set for elasticsearch and all the config has been left with default.

Also I have checked this link [How does high memory pressure affect performance?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-metrics-memory-pressure.html) but as you see server memory is far away from 75% memory usage.

**I must also mention that elasticsearch is inside ceph file system**

Comment: Are there any hints for peaks in ceph? Maybe slow requests are reported or deep-scrubbing is blocking IO. Have you checked something like `iostat` on the OSD servers?

Comment: Exactly! Last night I figured out the problem. Elasticsearch latency happens at same as Ceph deep-scrubbing. Elasticsearch server hard disk is HDD maybe slow hard disk is the cause.

Comment: It’s very likely, yes. There are several tweaks possible for deep-scrubbing, for example you can set specific intervals, how many parallel scrubs, sleeps between scrubs and some others. One more thing worth checking is how large the PGs are. The larger the PG size is the longer the scrubs take, which utilizes the OSDs more. If you have large PGs you can increase the pool‘s pg_num to split their size.